# Finding SVD matrices of a complex matrix in Java

Tags: java, android, matrix, linear-algebra, svd

I am currently working on an audio signal processing project and need to use SVD on a complex matrix in Java. My current linear algebra library is Apache Commons. However, it only provides SVD of real matrices and neither do JAMA, JBLAS, EJML, ojAlgo support complex SVD.

I had been using some tricks to find the SVD from an equivalent real matrix using the technique found [here](http://stemblab.github.io/complex-svd/). However, that technique comes with quite a major inaccuracy for the imaginary parts when I reconstruct the matrix.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone has an alternative workaround for me to find complex SVD using real SVD library or a library that supports complex SVD in java.

---

Here is how I have been doing it:

```
    //Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex> A = some matrix defined earlier
    Array2DRowRealMatrix AA = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(2 * row, 2 * col);
    Complex Aentry;

    for (int c = 0; c < row; c++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < col; s++) {
            Aentry = A.getEntry(c, s);

            AA.setEntry(c, s, Aentry.getReal());
            AA.setEntry(c, col + s, -Aentry.getImaginary());
            AA.setEntry(row + c, s, Aentry.getImaginary());
            AA.setEntry(row + c, col + s, Aentry.getReal());
        }
    }

    Array2DRowRealMatrix UU, SS, VV;

    svd = new SingularValueDecomposition(AA);

    UU = (Array2DRowRealMatrix) svd.getU();
    SS = (Array2DRowRealMatrix) svd.getS();
    VV = (Array2DRowRealMatrix) svd.getV();

    double[][] tempU = new double[row][2 * row];
    double[][] tempV = new double[col][2 * row];
    double[] tempS = new double[row];

    Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex> U = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix<>(ComplexField.getInstance(), row, row);
    Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex> S = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix<>(ComplexField.getInstance(), row, row);
    Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex> V = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix<>(ComplexField.getInstance(), col, row);
    Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex> recon, diff;

    UU.copySubMatrix(row, 2 * row - 1, 0, 2 * row - 1, tempU);
    VV.copySubMatrix(col, 2 * col - 1, 0, 2 * row - 1, tempV);

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            U.setEntry(i, j, new Complex(tempU[i][2 * j], tempU[i][2 * j + 1]));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            V.setEntry(i, j, new Complex(tempV[i][2 * j], tempV[i][2 * j + 1]));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        tempS[i] = SS.getEntry(i * row, i * row);
        if (tempS[i] == 0) {
            tempS[i] = EPSILON;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                S.setEntry(i, j, Complex.ZERO);
            }
        }

        S.setEntry(i, i, new Complex(tempS[i]));
    }

    recon = (Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex>)U.multiply(S).multiply(conjugate(V).transpose());
```

Comment: ojAlgo supports SVD for complex numbers.

Comment: @apete I couldn't find any documentation for the complex version at all...I only sees the real version

Comment: You simply use the factories named COMPLEX instead of PRIMITIVE – SingularValue.COMPLEX.make()

Comment: On a historical basis, [Jampack (JAva Matrix PACKage)](ftp://math.nist.gov/pub/Jampack/Jampack/AboutJampack.html) (from 1999) was the first Java implementation. You can find a bit more polished version [here](https://github.com/HullBend/cayley/tree/master/src/main/java/gov/nist/math/jampack)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use native libraries then [jeigen](https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen) is an option